# Python integer comparison (not equal to 0) benchmarks

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, timing

I was making a 2D physics engine in python for fun. I use an object's velocity to determine if I should run the collision detection on it. I.e if it's velocity would cause it to be inside another object on the next cycle, then I run the collision detection on it.

**Note: x and y velocities are always integers**

So I realised that I would have to check that the object's x or y velocities are either less than or greater than (not) 0.

There are a lot of ways to do this. I came up with 4 different methods:

```
def cmp1 (a,b):
    return a > 0 or a < 0 or b > 0 or b < 0

def cmp2 (a, b):
    return a != 0 or b != 0

def cmp3 (a, b):
    return abs(a | b) > 0

def cmp4 (a, b):
    return a | b != 0
```

I like the 4th method because it has the fewest operations and reads well in English
`a or b does not equal 0`

But of the 4 methods, and of the benchmarking method I used, it has the 2nd slowest average time which surprised me. In fact, the first method is the fastest (again, using the benchmarking method I used).

Here is the method I used to work out the timings:

```
def randints(min, max, amount):
    return tuple([random.randint(min, max) for i in range(amount)])

times = []
for i in range(1000):
    n = randints(-9999, 9999, 2)
    t = time.time() * 1000
    cmp4(*n)
    t2 = time.time() * 1000
    times.append(t2-t)

print('Average Time: ', sum(times)/len(times))
```

If I run this multiple times for each method, I get very consistent results:

cmp1 - 0.00027s

cmp2 - 0.00032s

cmp3 - 0.00037s

cmp4 - 0.00035s

So my question is **why is the 4th method so slow compared to the first?** surely 2 operations (one bitwise, one comparison) should be faster than 4.

And, yes, I know its a difference of only a couple of microseconds.

Comment: Perhaps because it doesn't always have to do four comparisons, only when `a == 0` do the last two get reached. But this seems like a premature optimisation, I would recommend using `cmp2`, which actually expresses the logic you want. Also note `timeit`.

Comment: Hint : In Python all objects have a boolean value. For integers, `0` is false and everything else is true. So your test can be simplified to `return a or b` (or `return bool(a or b)` if you want a proper boolean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better testing methods

```
y = [(random.randint(0,1), random.randint(0,1)) for _ in range(100_000)]

def test(cmp):
    [cmp(a, b) for a, b in y]

%timeit test(cmp1)
20.1 ms ± 315 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit test(cmp2)
17.3 ms ± 212 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit test(cmp3)
29.3 ms ± 588 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit test(cmp4)
21.9 ms ± 289 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The main advantage of `or` is that it is short circuiting, effectively equivalent to:

```
def or(a, b):
    if a: return a
    return b
```

Whereas `|` requires an actual (very low level) operation to be performed, then a new python integer object to be created and then another operation to be performed.

My test uses an array which is 50% zeros. If there was a larger or smaller percentage of of zeros the results may be quite different.

In any case, you forgot the fastest method of all (since all non-zero numbers are `True`):

```
def cmp0(a, b):
    return a or b

bool(cmp0(0, 0)), bool(cmp0(-12, 0)), bool(cmp0(3.14, 0))
# --> (False, True, True)

%timeit test(cmp0)
12.8 ms ± 191 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

However if you wanted to be as clear as possible (something at the heart of programming in python), I'd use `a != 0 or b != 0`.

Comment: Oh yeah. duh. Seems like I was thinking about it too mathematically and forgot basic python...